# "Click the link edit below" - the edit link is above

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The books area of careers.SE prompts you to add further details with the edit link. The prompt text is however slightly confused as to what is below.

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: This text also shows up on a page that's difficult to reach, and it makes way more sense on that page...

Comment: @nick another point for the up outside down approach, then!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removed "below". No more confusion, and this will work in any hemisphere... :-)

Answer (score 8):

Proposed solution:

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Hmm, too localized really. Southern hemisphere only.

Comment: @Bart Southern hemisphere users may be turned off if there is not a single thing upside down in the page. [No taxation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/2012-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/#comment-74218) [without representation!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/2012-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/#comment-74231)

Comment: ˙ʇɐɥʇ pǝɹǝpısuoɔ ʇ,upɐɥ ı 'sǝıboןodɐ ʎɯ

Comment: @badp: I think those comment targets are outdated now..